# Limit of integral.

Tags: real-analysis

Find the limit $$ \lim_{x\to 0}\int_{x}^{2x} e^{-t} dt$$. I tried it by expenson of exponential function but the integration is not allowed over infinite sum. Please solve it .Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get when you evaluate the integral?

Answer (score 4):

We know that $$\int_x^{2x} e^{-t}dt=\left[-e^{-t}\right]_x^{2x}=e^{-x}-e^{-2x},$$ so the limit is $$\lim_{x\to0}\int_x^{2x} e^{-t}dt=\lim_{x\to 0}(e^{-x}-e^{-2x})=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Other way: let $0<x<c<2x$ then your integral is equal to $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \int_x^c e^{-t} dt +\int_c^{2x} e^{-t}dt=\int_0^c e^{-t} dt-\int_0^c e^{-t} dt=0$$ the case $0^-$ is similar!

Answer (score 0):

Another way: for all $t$ near $0$ we have $|e^{-t}|<2$, so
$$\left|\int_x^{2x} e^{-t}\,dt\right|<2|2x-x|=2|x|\to0\ .$$

Comment: I deleted my post, I hadn't seen that you had basically done the same thing, and you posted ahead of me.

Comment: @zhw.  But people seem to like yours better ;-)  IMHO there's no problem having both, feel free to undelete it.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental theorem of calculus tells you that, if $f$ is a continuous function on some interval $(p,q)$ and $a\in(p,q)$, then the function
$$
F(x)=\int_{a}^x f(t)\,dt
$$
is differentiable (in particular continuous) on the interval $(p,q)$.

Since $f(x)=e^{-x}$ is continuous, we can apply this theorem. By observing that
$$
G(x)=\int_{x}^{2x}e^{-t}\,dt=
\int_{x}^0 f(t)\,dt+\int_0^{2x}f(t)\,dt
=F(2x)-F(x)
$$
(choosing $a=0$) we can deduce that $G$ is continuous (even differentiable) everywhere. Therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to0}G(x)=G(0)=F(0)-F(0)=0
$$